# Move up/down arrows in StackExchange Top Answers section are non-functional after being clicked

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I want to reorder the Top Answers section of my CV by moving one of the answers that is near the bottom of the list towards the top.

[image]

However, when I click the up arrow to move it up the list, the row moves up the list, but:

- the down arrow for the answer that is now above the answer (was 2 above the answer before clicking) has disappeared.
- the up arrow for the answer that is now below the answer I moved up is gone (was 1 above the answer before clicking).
- clicking on either the up or down arrows for the answer I moved does nothing.
- refreshing the page returns the answer to its original position in the list.

[image]

I am seeing this behavior in Chrome 21.  In IE8, the arrow buttons do nothing at all when clicking them.  I don't have Firefox/Opera/whatever installed to test with.

Comment: Which answer in particular on your profile?

Comment: @MattSherman this happens with any of them.

Comment: Seems like this way fixed at some point.